# R: Residual diagnostics in lmer, how should a plot look for averaged likert type data?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, residuals, likert

I conducted a within-subjects experiment (200 participants, 2 experimental conditions) and I want to develop a regression model tha predicts my measure value (which is based on averages derived from a 7 point likert scale) that also accounts for the demographics of the participants, age (continuous) andfamiliarity with technology (categorical). I ran the following model in R:

```
library(lme4)
library(lmerTest)
mod_lmer <- lmer(Measure ~ Age + Condition + Familiarity+ (1|Participant), data=dt_set)
summary(mod_lmer)
```

And then I would like to check residual diagnostics. I checked for residual normality with:

```
qqnorm(resid(mod_lmer))
qqline(resid(mod_lmer))
```

And everything looks ok. But then I tried to test for heteroscedasticity with:

```
plot(fitted(mod_lmer),resid(mod_lmer), main="Residuals vs Fitted")
abline(h=0,lty=2,col="blue")
```

And the plot was the following:

[image: residuals vs fitted values]

I am quite new to lmer so I am not sure how to interpret this. Definetely it doesn't look like what I would expect from a residual vs fitted plot of a linear regression. Any advice how should I interpret this result? Or if I missed anything in the process?

**EDIT**: I now checked the answer in : [Parallel straight lines on residual vs fitted plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38118/parallel-straight-lines-on-residual-vs-fitted-plot) and as it seems the issue is not related with lmer, but with the type of the dependent variable. However, the difference between the two questions is that, while in my plot there are also parallel lines, there is less of an implied structure (lines are homogeneously distributed in a way). So I am still unsure how to interpret this result.. Any ideas?

Comment: [Parallel straight lines on residual vs fitted plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/38118/parallel-straight-lines-on-residual-vs-fitted-plot)

Comment: This has nothing to do with mixed models. It's likely that the data are ordinal or discrete (eg counts) so you will need to fit a GLMM, not a LMM

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies. My data is not ordinal or counts, but they are derived from averaging likert scale data (so they are continuous but can take values between 1 and 7). So I am not sure how I should approach this (I updated my question following you answers)